# C# - Problem with reading XML more that once. Also error check if exists. [XElement]

Tags: c#

Updated with the changes suggested below.

I've been trying to de-bug this for about 2 days now for 3-4 hours on and off and haven't gotten far. Any help is appreciated.

Alright, so essentially this runs every time someone dies. If I run it once, it works fine. However, If I run it a second time it returns nothing.

```
public static string Death(string username)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            XElement kd = XElement.Load(path);
            Console.WriteLine("[SimplePlugin] Death Recorded for: " + username + "!");
            var player = kd.Elements("player").Single(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == username);

            int add = int.Parse(player.Element("deaths").Value) + 1; //Dies Here.

            player.SetElementValue("deaths", add);
            player.Save(path);
            kills = int.Parse(player.Element("kills").Value);
            deaths = int.Parse(player.Element("deaths").Value);
            return (username + " has " + kills + " kills and " + deaths + " deaths.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[SimpleStats] Writing SimpleConfig.XML...");
            XElement kd = new XElement(
            "SimpleStats",
            new XElement("player",
                new XAttribute("name", username),
            new XElement("kills", 0),
            new XElement("deaths", 0),
            new XElement("time", 0)));
            kd.Save(path);
            Console.WriteLine("[Simple] Done!");
            return (username + " has " + kills + " kills and " + deaths + " deaths.");
        }
    }
```

---

My second problem comes when the player name="NAME" in the XML already exists. Even if the username matches, it re-creates it.

Code for this:

```
public static string Load(string username)
    {

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            XElement kd = XElement.Load(path);
            var player = kd.Elements("player").SingleOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == username);
            Console.WriteLine(player);

            if (player == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[SimplePlugin] Writing new XML data for " + username + ".");
                kd.Add(new XElement("player",
                               new XAttribute("name", username),
                           new XElement("kills", 0),
                           new XElement("deaths", 0),
                           new XElement("time", 0)));
                kd.Save(path);
                return (username + " has " + kills + " kills and " + deaths + " deaths.");
            }
            else
            {
                kills = int.Parse(player.Element("kills").Value);
                deaths = int.Parse(player.Element("deaths").Value);
                return (username + " has " + kills + " kills and " + deaths + " deaths.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doesnt Exist");
            Console.WriteLine("[SimpleStats] Writing SimpleConfig.XML...");
            XElement player = new XElement(
            "SimpleStats",
            new XElement("player",
                new XAttribute("name", username),
            new XElement("kills", 0),
            new XElement("deaths", 0),
            new XElement("time", 0)));
            player.Save(path);
            Console.WriteLine("[Simple] Done!");
            return (username + " has " + kills + " kills and " + deaths + " deaths.");
        }
    }
```

A string is sent to Load(). Load check to see if the xml exists. If not, creates it. If so, creates it. Then check to see if the username exists in the xml data. If it does it reads it and returns that string. If it doesn't, it creates it.

Also: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"
How?

Comment: What do you mean with "it dies at that spot"? I assume you get an exception: which one?

Comment: An error message would help alot here. And why aren't you using a database for this?

Comment: Err, sorry didn't clarify that, by 'die' i mean doesnt return anything. Database?

Comment: Database - never mind ;-)... If performance is an issue, a database might be the better place to store these information.

Comment: Nah, It doesn't handle a lot.

Comment: You obviously modified your code since the original question. Could you update the question too?

Comment: Just updated it... will do it again to explain

Answer (score 2):

The second problem: you need to use `Value` property to get the attribute value.

```
var player = kd.Elements("player").SingleOrDefault(p => p.Attribute("name").Value == username);
```

You need to revise your entire code. For example, these lines will give you unexpected results:

```
kills = (int)player.Element("kills"); // explicit casting XElement to int, will  return the pointer value.
deaths = (int)player.Element("deaths");
```

The correct sequence is

```
kills = int.Parse(player.Element("kills").Value);
deaths = int.Parse(player.Element("deaths").Value);
```

Comment: Still creates new player element.

Comment: We don't see your actual code now, and we don't see your data. How are we supposed to help?

Answer (score 1):

For your first issue, do this

```
player.Element("deaths").Value = Convert.ToInt32(player.Element("deaths").Value) + 1;
```

As `XElement.Value` is of type `System.String`

Comment: Gives me error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'. Also still returns null.